# Show markers depending on Node ID via Openlayers

Tags: javascript

I have a situation that seems very easy, but i can't get it to work. I have a content type called 'countries' which hold all the countries. I want to display a map per country with the borders accentuated.

Here for i have two views, 'data' and 'display' to show an Openlayers map. When i add the 'display' view to my panel, i nicely get the last ten records (because in the 'data' view i've chosen to display a specified number of items | 10 items).

Now i don't want to display the last ten records, but only the records that correspondents with the node id, passed via the url. So i added an contextual filter to my 'data' view and when i test it, it works. The 'data' view only shows the according records.

The problem is that i can't find a way to make the 'display' view dependent on the 'data' view. I've tried to first add the 'data' view and right below the 'display' view in my panel, but it keeps outputting the last ten records.

What setting am i missing?